# A colorful affix riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix usually wears black and yellow (or yellow and black to shake things up a bit)
> My infix is commonly blue, brown or green, but can look red when immortalized
> My suffix comes in different colors, green, black or even yellow. I like mine black, thank you.
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you perhaps

> a "bit"?

My prefix usually wears black and yellow (or yellow and black to shake things up a bit)

> This sounds like a bee; most bees are black and yellow (or yellow and black), leaving aside the blue ones.

My infix is commonly blue, brown or green, but can look red when immortalized

> These are common eye colors. Redeye occurs in photographs when the flash catches blood vessels in the eyes.

My suffix comes in different colors, green, black or even yellow. I like mine black, thank you.

> These all sound like different types of teas. Black tea, green tea, and yellow tea are all different types of tea.

All together,

> "bee", "eye", and "tea" spell out the word BIT. This is a concept that has to do with [digitally storing colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color).

Comment: Really thought it was going to take longer than this, congrats!

Comment: I’m guessing the ‘shake things up a bit’ is a reference to The Bee Movie, since that’s some of the first dialog in it.

Comment: @Buzzyy Indeed it is!